# Can I ask topic related to Facebook Ad Settings in SO

Tags: discussion, scope

Can I ask question related to Facebook Ad settings?

I'm not able change the timezone of my Fb ad account. I read [this article](https://www.facebook.com/business/help/754049591334898) but it does't seems to be working for me. I also [posted a question](https://www.facebook.com/business/help/community/question/?id=1594832303897029) in their support form but still wait for any one to help.

If SO is not a best place to ask this question then which stackexchange network is best fit for this kind of issue?

Comment: It's definitely off-topic on SO because it's not about programming.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, you are asking a question about an online application *as an end user*. You are not programming something here, this is not software development, and so it is off-topic for Stack Overflow.

There is a dedicated Stack Exchange site for online web applications like Facebook, called Web Applications. Quoting [their help center](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

> **Web Applications Stack Exchange** is for expert and advanced users of web applications.
>
> If your question generally covers …
>
> - Using Gmail, Facebook, Twitter, Google, or any other website which **behaves like an application**
>
> [...]
>
> … then you’re in the right place to ask your question!

Do check the rest of the points made in that help topic before posting your question, just to make sure you are in the right place.

Comment: thank you very much. I'll defiantly check that site.

Answer (score 1):

If you were not someone involved with software development, would you ever encounter the issue you are asking about? Reading your question it seems a very unlikely situation. There's no indication that someone not involved in software development wouldn't have the same issue you are experience, and the topic itself lends to be very uncommon that there would be an issue that only a software developer would have.

Comment: Got your point, thanks. Is there any stackexchange site for this? and I thought there are some FB developer in SO, which might see this and help me as I think this is a bug.

Comment: @Raunak some of these devs are indeed here. That doesn't mean it's on topic to ask them about non-programming stuff. I unfortunately don't believe there is much you can do here. I can't think of any Stack Exchange site that would fit your  question. Their forum seems to be the best place to post.

Comment: @RaunakGupta: such questions would probably be on-topic for [Web Applicatons](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).